# php select boxes auto filled from another

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to auto fill 2 select boxes on a Web page.

When the user selects a class, select box 2 auto has options Main Spec the person plays.  When the user selects Tank (for example), select box 3 auto has options for Race

I have managed it with 2nd getting populated from 1st but it has the 3rd options

http://daemonknight.atspace.co.uk/apply.php - to view page in question

```
<?php include("includes/classcheck.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/racecheck.php"); ?>

<tr>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td><select id="class" name="class" onchange="populate('class','mainspec')")>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Death Knight">Death Knight</option>
        <option value="Druid">Druid</option>
        <option value="Hunter"> Hunter </option>
        <option value="Mage"> Mage </option>
        <option value="Paladin">Paladin</option>
        <option value="Priest"> Priest </option>
        <option value="Rogue"> Rogue </option>
        <option value="Shaman"> Shaman </option>
        <option value="Warlock"> Warlock </option>
        <option value="Warrior"> Warrior </option>
        <option value="Monk"> Monk </option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Main Spec</td>
    <td><select id="mainspec" name="mainspec" onchange="populate('mainspec','race')")></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Race</td>
    <td><select id="race" name="race"></select></td>
</tr>
```

-----------------classcheck.php------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);

    s2.innerHTML ="";
    if (s1.value=="Paladin"){
        var optionArray=["|","Healer|Healer","Tank|Tank","DPS|DPS"];
    } else if (s1.value=="Death Knight"){
        var optionArray=["|","Tank|Tank","DPS|DPS"];
    } else if (s1.value=="Druid"){
        var optionArray=["|","Healer|Healer","Tank|Tank","MDPS|MDPS","RDPS|RDPS"];
    } else if (s1.value=="Hunter"){
        var optionArray=["|","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Mage"){
        var optionArray=["|","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Priest"){
        var optionArray=["|","Healer|Healer","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Rogue"){
        var optionArray=["|","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Shaman"){
        var optionArray=["|","Healer|Healer","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Warlock"){
        var optionArray=["|","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Warrior"){
        var optionArray=["|","Tank|Tank","DPS|DPS"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Monk"){
        var optionArray=["|","Tank|Tank","Healer|Healer","DPS|"];
    }

    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);      
    }
}
</script>
```

----------------------racecheck.php--------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);

    s2.innerHTML ="";
    if (s1.value=="Paladin"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Draenei|Draenei"];
    } else if (s1.value=="Death Knight"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Gnome|Gnome","Draenei|Draenei","Worgen|Worgen"];
    } else if (s1.value=="Druid"){
        var optionArray=["|","Night Elf|Night Elf","Worgen|Worgen"];
    } else if (s1.value=="Hunter"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Draenei|Draenei","Worgen|Worgen","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Mage"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Gnome|Gnome","Draenei|Draenei","Worgen|Worgen","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Priest"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Gnome|Gnome","Draenei|Draenei","Worgen|Worgen","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Rogue"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Gnome|Gnome","Worgen|Worgen","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Shaman"){
        var optionArray=["|","Dwarf|Dwarf","Draenei|Draenei","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Warlock"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Gnome|Gnome","Worgen|Worgen"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Warrior"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Gnome|Gnome","Draenei|Draenei","Worgen|Worgen","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }else if (s1.value=="Monk"){
        var optionArray=["|","Human|Human","Dwarf|Dwarf","Night Elf|Night Elf","Gnome|Gnome","Draenei|Draenei","Pandaren|Pandaren"];
    }

    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);      
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your "question" currently lacks details. Such as actual code.

Comment: Hope the coding now attached can help.

Answer (score -1):

use JQuery/Javascript, just like in the example

http://jsfiddle.net/4po4wt0x/

```
<select id='countries'>
<option></option>
<option value='scotland'> Scotland </option>
<option value='england'>England </option>
```

```
$("#countries").change( function() { 
if ($("#countries").val()=='scotland') {
        $("#cities").append("<option>Glasgow</option>");
        $("#cities").append("<option>Edinburgh</option>")
    }

});
```

Comment: I can get the select option to work from 1 to 2 but the problem lies when I add a 3rd - option for 3 goes into 2

Comment: been trying this method but cant get the items to display on the 2nd select box